# Vtiger: "Permission to perform the operation is denied for id"

Tags: java, android, sql-update, vtiger

I am using Vwsclib (Java version) in order to use vtiger webservices. All works fine, queries, login...but I noticed that this library doesn't have a doUpdate() method, so instead I use doInvoke().

The code is like this:

```
valuesmap.put("id", json.get("id").toString());
JSONObject jo=(org.json.simple.JSONObject) client.doInvoke("update",valuesmap,"POST");
```

However, when I use it the server returns an error:

{"message":"Permission to perform the operation is denied for id","code":"ACCESS_DENIED"}

Do you know what could be the solution of this problem?

Comment: A valid login and permissions to use the webservice. Otherwise programming skills :(

Comment: Or in this case, a library bug

Comment: Sad. Have a look at my vtiger repo on github. Maybe we can join forces sometimes: https://github.com/SteffenKockel/vtiger. I Already did a few things, although it's relatively new.